# Why are parts of the image rendering so grainy or pixelated? (Blender 2.79)

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render something I've been working on, but every time I try, it doesn't fully render. I'm using cycles render in version 2.79. In the center of the piece, there's a cloud. The cloud barely renders at all. There are other areas around the image that didn't render properly, either. The main problem area is the cloud. I used the cloud generator add-on.

When I say "doesn't fully render", I mean that some spots all over the image are super grainy and pixelated. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image: This is the problematic rendered image.]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @susu Thank you for the feedback. I have edited my question.

Comment: The render resolution and frame range are not relevant, please post an image of the samples section, and also show the nodes for the material used on the clouds.

Comment: @susu Sorry, I guess I'm pretty new to blender. How can I get to the samples section?